# javascript error object expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

While executing the code below i am getting javascript error "expected object" though i am able to run same piece of code in another solution. Pleae help.

```
   $(document).ready(function ()
        {

            $('a.desc').click(function () 
               {
                 $('label input[type="text"]').val($(this).html()).keyup();
           });
           $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
           bTable = $("#invoiceSummary").dataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,

            "bLengthChange": true,

            "bFilter": true,

            "bSort": true,

            "bInfo": true,

            "bAutoWidth": true,

            "bJQueryUI": true,

            "iDisplayLength": 25

        });
    });
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? Try running it in Firefox with Firebug installed to get more useful debug information

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Maybe use Chrome or Firefox to debug your Javascript code and figure out exactly where it breaks? That would help to answer your question.

Comment: My instinct suggests it may be one of your selectors not matching anything. Try enclosing every statement where you are selecting something in an if statement, checking that it exists, like so: if ($('a.desc')) { //rest of code here... }

Comment: error is coming in the first line, the code is working fine in another solution even here it was doing good when this appeared suddenly. Selectors seem to be fine.

Comment: $('label input[type="text"]').val($(this).html ... I think $(this) in this case refers to the current a, try $(this).text() instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is within either the prettyPhoto or dataTable plugin. I deduced this with the following reasoning:

1. There are no syntax errors that I can see
2. Sometimes a selector can return 0 elements. If $('a.desc') or $('label input[type="text"]') were to return 0 elements then this would not cause an error as the jquery functions .click(), .val(), .html(), and .keyup() obviously can cope with empty collections
3. Can prettyPhoto() and dataTable() handle an empty collection? No idea because I don't know the plugins. Even if the collections were not empty (i.e. results were returned for $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']") and $("#invoiceSummary")) then perhaps these plugins were expecting a certain parameter to be passed in but never received it.

My recommendation would be to see whether the selectors for the prettyPhoto and dataTable plugins are returning any elements, and also to check that you are supplying everything required for those plugins as parameters. If you're satisfied that you are then I would suspect there is a bug or another dependency is missing.